# discrepancy between Float32Array and DataView

Tags: javascript, dataview

Thought I understood how Float32Array works, but it looks like I'm not quite there.
In the simplest example possible:

```
buffer = new ArrayBuffer(128);
dataView = new DataView(buffer);
floatArray = new Float32Array(buffer);

dataView.setFloat32(8, 7);
console.log(floatArray[2]); //prints gibberesh
```

The way I understood it, the data view should set a float starting at the 8th byte to be 7,
so the third float in the float array I would expect to be 7.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: You mean `dv.setFloat32(8, 7);` ?

Comment: oops, fixed typo, also index at 2, not 3 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes it work, the last parameter being `littleEndian`

```
dataView.setFloat32(8, 7, true);
```

This might be better, although I can't say for sure. Presumably Float32Array always uses the system's littleEndian, while DataView can use either.

```
var littleEndian = (function() {
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(2);
  new DataView(buffer).setInt16(0, 256, true);
  return new Int16Array(buffer)[0] === 256;
})();

dataView.setFloat32(8, 7, littleEndian);
```

Comment: huh, funny that they don't both default do doing the same thing.  Thanks!

Comment: I have the impression *Array was meant for computations, and DataView for binary files.